# SCSS / SASS Background image url change

Tags: css, background, sass

I have this in SCSS:

```
@include background(image-url("test.jpg") no-repeat center top);
```

How can i change the image-url. Now the image-url give /img/. How can i change that path?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the path with `images_dir` variable, which is located in the config.rb file of your compass project's root folder.

ex.

```
# Default
images_dir = "img"
# Customized
images_dir = "pictures"
```

More info at the compass [docs](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/urls/)